# FlowType.js won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a portfolio for myself and want to use FlowType.js for a responsive font but i can't get it working. I have tried every Google hit but none of them helped me out. Could you please look at my code?

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <LINK HREF="stylesheet/style.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">
    <title>Portfolio Daan Heijmans</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flowtype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="naam">
                DAAN HEIJMANS
            </div>
            <div id="navigatie_links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#biografie">BIOGRAFIE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#vakken">VAKKEN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="navigatie_rechts">
                <li><a href="nl/index.php">NL /</a></li>
                <li><a href="en/index.php">EN</a></li>
            </div>
            <img src="images/achtergrond_portfolio.png">
            <div id="vakken_navigatie">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">DED2 |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> PPM2 |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> PTM2 |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> SCO2 |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> UXU2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('wrapper').flowtype();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my CSS

```
body{
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFF;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
font-family: "Montserrat Hairline";
overflow: scroll;
font-size: 30px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

#wrapper{
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#header {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}

#header img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}

#naam{
width: 70%;
background-color: black;
float: left;
font-size: 1em;
color: white;
}

#navigatie_links{
width: 20%;
background-color: black;
float: left;
font-size: 1em;
color: white;
}

ul, li, a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
}

#navigatie_rechts{
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background-color: black;
float: right;
font-size: 1em;
color: white;
}

#vakken_navigatie{
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 10%;
margin: -15% auto 0 28%;
font-size: 1.68em;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (_"why isn't this code working?"_) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  $('wrapper').flowtype(); to  $('#wrapper').flowtype();